# What kind of group-like object is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, magma

Define a magma $\langle G,*\rangle$ with

1. $\forall a,b \in G,\quad   a*b \in G $
2. $\exists 1(a*1=a\;\text{  and }\;1*a=1)$
3. $\forall a \in G,  \exists b (a*b=1)$
4. $\exists c \forall a \in G, \quad(a*c=1)$

(associativity and commutativity does not need to always hold)

Could you please let me know the name of these kinds of magma?

---

Thanks for your comments. This looks like a kind of unital loop-like object.

---

Finally someone asked for an example. Well, I am surprised that nobody noticed that I am just restating the properties of one of the most seen operations.

Comment: FYI, "groupoid" is an actual kind of mathematical object with a specific definition. (They actually come up a lot in certain areas of math, too.) "Group-like object" might be a better generic term for "something that's kind of like a group."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra) ... go to the section on types of magma ... I think it might be a loop ?

Comment: 2 and 3 look very strange. Are you sure they are as you ment? Especially $1*a=1$ in 2 and $\exists b\forall a$ instead of $\forall a\exists b$ in 3. Also is the universal quantification in $a$ before or behind the $\exists1$?

Comment: @LowGPA this doesn't help to know where is the $\forall a$ in 2. (before or after $\exists1$?).

Comment: @Surb both work. $1*a=1$ was intented

Comment: @M.Winter Both ∀a∃b and ∃b∀a work. I rewrite it to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: @LowGPA "$\exists b\forall a$" is quite different from "$\forall a\exists b$" - do you mean that there is a *single* $b$ which, when multiplied on the right, always yields $1$, or that for each $a$ there is a corresponding $b$?

Comment: I meant both conditions should be satisfied.

Comment: Do you have examples of these kind of objects?

Comment: @Joppy $x*y=x^y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure is modeled off of exponentiation. But if its identity is not two-sided, it has an absorption element, and is not associative, it is not very "group-like." Indeed, despite monoids having absorption elements, their identities and absorption elements are still two-sided, so it's not even monoid-like. I will go on a whim and guess there is not a standard name for the structure you describe (or if there is, it is very obscure and the structure is something I'd call uninteresting).

Given how natural of an operation exponentiation is, you might be tempted to think it odd abstract algebra hasn't distilled from it a type of algebraic structure. But I think it's best instead to interpret it in a different context: **right actions**.

Let $R$ be a set and $(N,\circ)$ an algebraic structure (letters chosen reminiscent of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$). Consider an operation $\wedge: R\times N\to R$. Here is an axiom we might like it to satisfy:

$$ (r\wedge n_1)\wedge n_2=r\wedge (n_1\circ n_2) \tag{1}$$

This means that every element of $N$ acts as a function of $R$ "from the right." In practice, it'd make the most sense for $R$ and $N$ to be groups or at least monoids. One common example of this is *right group actions*. Natural occurrences of right group actions are of $G$ on $\hom(G,X)$ when $X$ is a set, also known as the contragredient action in representation theory, of which $S_n$ acting on a Cartesian power $X^n$ or a tensor power $V^{\otimes n}$ are special cases, and monodromy actions of fundamental groups on fibers of covering maps.

If $(R,\cdot)$ itself has an operation, then we might add another axiom:

$$ (r_1\cdot r_2)\wedge n=(r_1\wedge n)\cdot (r_2\wedge n) \tag{2}$$

This says that $(N,\circ)$ acts from the right *by endomorphisms* of $R$. (Or, if $N$ is a group, then it acts by automorphisms.) In general, to any monoid $(R,\cdot)$ there is an associated monoid $(N,\circ)$ of right endomorphisms. An example where this occurs is in Galois theory: Galois groups act by automorphisms (with respect to both addition and multiplication operations in fact), albeit from the left instead of the right (but any left action may be converted to a right action and vice-versa).

Another important example of where this occurs is conjugation in a group. Conjugation by a specific element is usually treated as a left automorphism - that is, $\varphi_g(x):=gxg^{-1}$ satisfies $\varphi_g(xy)=\varphi_g(x)\varphi_g(y)$ - but occasionally group theorists will prefer a compactified and suggestive exponential notation $x^g:=g^{-1}xg$ which is a *right* action by automorphisms. In this notation, both $(xy)^g=x^gy^g$ and $(x^g)^h=x^{gh}$ are true, exactly like exponentiation.

Finally, yet another axiom we could add could be

$$ (r\wedge n_1)\cdot (r\wedge n_2)=r\wedge (n_1\oplus n_2), \tag{3}$$

where here we write $\oplus$ for an operation in $N$. If $(N,\oplus,\circ)$ is a  ring, all three axioms makes $R$ an $N$-module! In particular, this means the positive reals $R=(\mathbb{R}^{>0},\cdot)$ is a one-dimensional real vector space over the reals $N=(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$. This is an extremely important intuition to have when using all of the exponent laws in intermediate algebra (while of course an elementary algebra student will not have access to lingo like "vector space" or "action" or "homomorphism," this concept is still ultimately behind everything).

Comment: I love your answer! I am currently reading a book on module theories. In first chapter the author listed many examples of modules, including the ones related to polynomials, series, vector spaces, and ideals. BUT why he did not list $\mathbb{R}$ as one of the most seen $\mathbb{N}$-module with ^operation?

Comment: @LowGPA You mean $\Bbb R^{>0}$ as an $\Bbb R$-module, or $\Bbb Z$-module if you wish. (The accepted definition of module is over a ring, and rings have additive inverses, which $\Bbb N$ does not, so you'll have to expand $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$ to talk about a module, in which case you might as well expand to $\Bbb R$.) Presumably because it didn't come to mind while the author was writing - their mind might have been in loftier places than intermediate algebra. Also, modules are usually interpreted additively (with scalar multiplication), not multiplicatively (with scalar exponentiation).

Comment: Is the name of "module" originally came from $7 \equiv 1$ (modulo 3)? Every abelian group (0,1,2) is a Z-module: 2*8=1, 2*6=0

Comment: @LowGPA Not that I know of. Note I am talking about [these modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). (Most sources treat left modules, but here I am talking about right modules.)